# Combine and resort PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to combine and resort elements into categorized arrays. See how $Start is organized compared to $Finish.

Could you please explain, and perhaps show, how to efficiently make this conversion?

Thanks!

```
$Start = array(
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateA'),
    array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateB'),
    array ('Doctor3', 'visitDateC'),
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateD'),
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateE'),
    array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateF'),
    array ('Doctor4', 'visitDateG')
    );


$Finish = array(
    array (
        'Doctor1',
        array('visitDateA', 'visitDateD', 'visitDateE')),
    array (
        'Doctor2',
        array('visitDateB', 'visitDateF')),
    array (
        'Doctor3',
        array('visitDateC')),
    array (
        'Doctor4',
        array('visitDateG'))
    );
```

Comment: Can you please explain `resort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the result exactly the way you need it:

```
$Start = array(
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateA'),
    array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateB'),
    array ('Doctor3', 'visitDateC'),
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateD'),
    array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateE'),
    array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateF'),
    array ('Doctor4', 'visitDateG')
    );

$Doctors = $Finish = array();
foreach( $Start as $item ) {
  if ( !isset( $Doctors[$item[0]] ) ) {
    $Doctors[$item[0]] = array( $item[0], array() );
    $Finish[] = &$Doctors[$item[0]];
  }
  if ( !in_array( $item[1], $Doctors[$item[0]][1] ) )
    $Doctors[$item[0]][1][] = $item[1];
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need to get the ball rolling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you want, but I would suggest this. As it would be easy to access the values in the code.

```
<?php

$Start = array(
array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateA'),
array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateB'),
array ('Doctor3', 'visitDateC'),
array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateD'),
array ('Doctor1', 'visitDateE'),
array ('Doctor2', 'visitDateF'),
array ('Doctor4', 'visitDateG')
);

foreach($Start as $k => $v){
    if(in_array($v[0], $v)){
        $Finish[$v[0]][] = $v[1];
    }
}
ksort($Finish); // Doctor1 will always be first.
print_r($Finish);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Doctor1] => Array
        (
            [0] => visitDateA
            [1] => visitDateD
            [2] => visitDateE
        )

    [Doctor2] => Array
        (
            [0] => visitDateB
            [1] => visitDateF
        )

    [Doctor3] => Array
        (
            [0] => visitDateC
        )

    [Doctor4] => Array
        (
            [0] => visitDateG
        )

)
```

To access you can then write something like this:

```
if(in_array('visitDateA', $Finish['Doctor1'])){
    echo 'Yes' . PHP_EOL;
}
else{
    echo 'No' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
Yes
```